# elastic beanstalk configuration error

Tags: php, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to launch an app on elastic beanstalk in the php 5.5 container.  there are 3 environments dev, staging and production.  You cannot distinguish between environments when setting environment variables from the command line so I am using a workaround suggested by aws support which is to run a shell script on deployment to set the variables depending on the existence of another variable I can vary depending on environment

.When i deploy my app there is a config file in .ebextensions/ like so

```
container_commands:
  command01:
    command: "./.ebextensions/setEnvVars.sh"
```

the shell script is also in .ebextensions and it looks like so

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$PARAM1" in
        "development")
                echo -e "SetEnv APP_ENV development\n
                         SetEnv DB_HOST *******\n
                         SetEnv DB_NAME *******\n
                         SetEnv DB_USERNAME *******\n
                         SetEnv DB_PASSWORD *******\n" > .htaccess
                ;;
        "production")
                echo -e "SetEnv APP_ENV production\n
                         SetEnv DB_HOST *******\n
                         SetEnv DB_NAME *******\n
                         SetEnv DB_USERNAME *******\n
                         SetEnv DB_PASSWORD *******\n" > .htaccess
                ;;
        "staging")
                echo -e "SetEnv APP_ENV staging\n
                         SetEnv DB_HOST *******\n
                         SetEnv DB_NAME *******\n
                         SetEnv DB_USERNAME *******\n
                         SetEnv DB_PASSWORD *******\n" > .htaccess
                ;;
esac

if [ -f .htaccess ]; then
        chmod 644 .htaccess
fi
```

when the app deploys I get this error

```
[Instance: i-400fc60f Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command command01 failed .
```

and this is what I think is the relevant ecert from the logs

```
2014-02-03 12:54:25,531 [INFO] (1923 MainThread) [command.py-130] [root command execute] Command returned: (code: 1, stdout: Error occurred during build: Command command01 failed
, stderr: None)
2014-02-03 12:54:25,533 [DEBUG] (1923 MainThread) [commandWrapper.py-60] [root commandWrapper main] Command result: {'status': 'FAILURE', 'results': [{'status': 'FAILURE', 'config_sets': ['Infra-WriteRuntimeConfig', 'Infra-WriteApplication1', 'Infra-WriteApplication2', 'Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild', 'Hook-PreAppDeploy', 'Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild', 'Hook-EnactAppDeploy', 'Hook-PostAppDeploy'], 'returncode': 1, 'events': [], 'msg': 'Error occurred during build: Command command01 failed\n'}], 'api_version': '1.0'}
```

I don't have any experience with elastic beanstalk or shell so there could easily be a syntax error but I honestly dont know were to look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, but this is why working with `.ebextentions` is such great fun!

From the log you appended, the only thing I'm able to see is that it's in fact your command named `command01` that failed. Exactly *what* went wrong is typically an enigma of trial-and-error.

This is exactly the place to bring back any old skills you may have in "printf()-debugging". Anything you echo from the scripts you call will also be output into the same log file (`/var/log/cfn-init.log`), allowing you to grok what's going on...

Looking at your scripts, however, my guess would be that $PARAM1 is undefined. Try passing it as a parameter to your shell script in your `container_command` like so:

```
container_commands:
    command01:
        command: "./.ebextensions/setEnvVars.sh" ${PARAM1}
```

And then use the first argument in your Bash `case` statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    ...
esac
```

Good luck!

---

Edit: Oh, one more thing. You'll of course need to set the `PARAM1` parameter in your AWS Console. You do this in `Configuration` > `Software Configuration` > `Environment Properties`. Just in case you haven't done this already...

Answer (score 1):

A useful trick for debugging issues with scripts is to redirect stdout/stderr to a file.

```
commands:
  command-00:
    command: my_command args >> commands.out 2&>1
```